# Tailwind CSS how to style a href links in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

For some reason, tailwind seems to have removed the "blue" and "underlined" part of http links.

How do I get this functionality back?

For example, in my React code, i have:

```
return (
  <a href={v.url}>{v.alias}</a>
);
```

but this link shows up like normal font, and there's no underline. there's also no notion for browser to remember or hover different color on the link.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Tailwind's [Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) functionality will remove all of the browsers' default stylings for most elements, giving you a clean basis to start from, to make cross-browser styling more consistent.

You need to re-add the styles you wish, for example:

```
className="underline text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800 visited:text-purple-600"
```

or:

```css
a {
   @apply underline text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800 visited:text-purple-600
}
```

Comment: Imagine having to style `<a> links` :(

Comment: Most well-designed websites will style anchor tags to make the colours and fonts match their branding. The default browser stylings on various elements can cause issues and inconsistencies with this, which is why Preflight resets all default styles to start from a blank page.

Comment: This solution works but it requires some configuration beforehand to use `visited:text-purple-600`. I've made a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597301/8886761) to elaborate.

Comment: To update my old comment - you don't need to do the extra configuration with Tailwind 3, but you will with Tailwind 2.

Comment: Thanks, i wasted 1 hour trying to figure this out for my project in vue.

Answer (score 10):

So the other answers correctly have pointed out that preflight and/or base will reset the components, but you can also use the [@layer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) and [@apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) directives to apply classes to elements in bulk.

@layer gives you a bucket to put things into, the ones currently available in Tailwind would be like base, components, and utilities.

For example, if you wanted to set all links to blue and underline, you could do the following:

```
@layer base {
  a {
    @apply text-blue underline
  }
}
```

The linked examples show how you could group the elements to make a meta-class for styling buttons consistently.

```
@layer components {
  .btn-blue {
    @apply bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT: It appears that this extra configuration is not needed with Tailwind 3 (at least as tested with 3.1.1). It may still be needed if you use Tailwind 2. See Patrik's comment below for an example.**

---

As Luke correctly explained, Tailwind's Preflight removes all the browser defaults. You'll have to add the styling yourself:

```
className="underline text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800 visited:text-purple-600"
```

However, you can't just use `visited:` with `text-purple-600` without some configuration (at least with Tailwind 2. I'm not familiar with older versions). You'll also need to add the following to your Tailwind config at your project root:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      textColor: ['visited'],
    }
  },
}
```

That way, Tailwind will make all the classes with `visited:` available for use with all the text color classes.

[You can learn more about enabling extra variants in the Tailwind docs.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants#enabling-extra-variants)

Comment: luke's answer appears to work without any configuration : https://play.tailwindcss.com/q4vo2yEzsb

Comment: @patrikcsak Good to know! At the time I posted my answer it wasn't like that (if you change the version to Tailwind 2 in your example you can see what I mean). I guess the `visted:` prefix now works with text colors by default. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with others here who suggest re-adding the default anchor tag styling as a solution. You can do this, but one annoyance of working with normal anchor tags is when you wrap a button in an anchor tag, the styling cascades into the text on the button, which is super annoying.

Instead, I would suggest creating your own utility class that applies these styles instead of changing the styles for all `<a>` tags. For example:

```
.hyperlink {
  @apply text-blue-600 underline
}

.hyperlink:visited {
  @apply text-purple-600
}
```

Now, use that class explicitly when you want it rather than applying it no matter what.

```html
<a class="hyperlink" href="/foo/bar">Text link</a>
<a href="foo/bar"><button>Style-Free Button!</button></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

This applies to version `2.*`. It is not an issue in tailwind 3

---

If you are using `@apply` note that the states (like hover) **cannot** be added in-line like you would pass to a class.

```css
a {
   @apply underline text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800 visited:text-purple-600
}
```

They need to be broken out and matched to the css states like this:

```css
a {
   @apply underline text-blue-600
}
a:hover {
   @apply text-blue-800
}
a:visited {
   @apply text-purple-600
}
```

Comment: Is this possibly no longer true on a newer version?  I'm having no issue with the initial code blurb and hover/visited being applied.  I'm on tailwind 3.3.

Comment: correct, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

tailwind.config.js

```js
extend: {
    content: {
        'externalLink': "url('images/icons/icon-external.svg')",
    }
},
```

In css

```css
a {
    @apply underline underline-offset-4 decoration-1 decoration-primary;

    &:hover {
        @apply no-underline bg-tertiary/20;
    }

    &:visited {
        @apply text-primary;
    }

    &[target="_blank"]:after {
        @apply content-externalLink inline-block ml-1 mt-1;
    }
}
```